# What is the "RegExp DoS issue"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, minimatch

I just installed nodejs in a server and a basic `npm install` shows a lot of messages like this:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.4.0 should be installed with -g
```

Note the message appearing to the right:

```
npm WARN ... or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In my local server, I was already using minimatch 3.0.3. However, since the server was not using the last version of node, this is new to me and started to investigate:

This issue being reported in [npm's github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13323) and mentions to it in other questions. In general, it gets solved by upgrading the version of `minimatch` to at least 3.0.2.

However, I wonder what is this RegExp DoS issue? Is there any specific regex that was allowing a DoS attack through minimatch? I cannot imagine how this could happen and don't want to reproduce it, but I fail to find more documentation and [minimatch's Github list of issues](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20) does not have any trace of it.

From the [releases pages](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/releases) I see [the only commit for the 3.0.2 release](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/commit/6944abf9e0694bd22fd9dad293faa40c2bc8a955), in which basically the regex syntax is being encapsulated (I am not familiar enough with JavaScript to follow all of it to the last tiny detail).

Comment: The issue is documented [here](https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/minimatch_regular-expression-denial-of-service).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the commit you link to (https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch/commit/6944abf9e0694bd22fd9dad293faa40c2bc8a955):

The test added in the commit is making a regex like this:

```
var exploit = '!(' + genstr(1024 * 15, '\\') + 'A)'
```

That is creating a string starting `'!('`, then 1024*15 copies of `\`, then `'A)'`. That must be the DoS condition.

This line

```
tail = tail.replace(/((?:\\{2}){0,64})(\\?)\|/g, function (_, $1, $2) {
```

is probably the one that was choking.

Comment: Great one! This matches with the explanation in the [official source](https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/minimatch_regular-expression-denial-of-service) robertklep mentioned in comments.